# Emulator target dropdown is missing in Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

There are a lot of posts from users who complain their emulator dropdown is empty (no devices listed). Well, I have similar but different problem -- I don't have this dropdown at all.

I installed VS 2015, after that I rerun the installer to add Xamarin, then I updated Xamarin to the latest stable version, I hit this problem. So I removed Xamarin, installed it again, and then updated -- same story.

When I load VS and Xamarin/Android project I can see in output pane adb is started, 2 devices detected, everything correct. Except I cannot even choose the device because I have no mean to choose.

What do I need to get this dropdown?

[image: Emulator dropdown in VS]

Update:

- monodroid log -- http://pastebin.com/XVq11kYq
- Ide log -- http://pastebin.com/vUpaA4HW

Comment: Upload your log files which can be gathered from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Log`. Specifically the `IDE` and `monodroid` ones.

Comment: @JonDouglas, thank you, I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you see anything in that area where the drop down is supposed to be? IOW do you at least get a little green play arrow with "Start" Next to it? E.G.:

[image]

If you do not see even that "Start", E.G.:

[image]

then you might just have the control disabled. If so, the click the little down arrow at the end of the toolbar, E.G.:

[image]

and then hover over "Add or Remove buttons" and select the "Debug Targets" to add the device selection control to the toolbar.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for some elaborate combo as in screenshot in my question, while in fact this combo looks was all the time enabled and simply looked like in your screenshot (with nested list of devices).